# Python script taking several hundred MB of memory

Tags: python, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have a Python script that runs for about 10 minutes.

As it runs, it gradually consumes RAM. It starts out with about 77MB then ends with 216MB.

It doesn't really do anything that memory intensive. It does create a large number of ActiveRecord object, some of which form large graphs with other ActiveRecord objects. The graphs can contain several dozen nodes.  However, I fully expect `gc` to detect any cyclic references and free them as the graphs go out of scope, which they do periodically throughout the duration of the script's execution.

When I use `gc.get_objects`, I see that, after I run `gc.collect()`, there are always 0 objects in generations 0 and 1. However, generation 2 has 105K object when things get going, and ends with about 1.1 million objects when the script finishes.  This causes problems, since I am using a small machine with only about 1GB of RAM. (I don't mean to imply I understand Python's memory management very well. Pretty much all I know about it has come from the time spent trying to figure out this problem).

Most of the script is pure Python, though it does use the MySQLdb library to interface the ActiveRecord objects with MySQL.

Should I consider this behavior normal for Python and just buy more RAM? Or should I view this as a memory leak. As time progresses, the script will get bigger and take more time to run, so I'm concerned that I will just have to buy more and more RAM as time goes on.

Comment: You'll have to supply your code for us to say anything about it.

Comment: CPython uses *reference counting* counting as it's memory management strategy. If you still have non-cyclic references alive, the whole graph will stay in memory, regardless of what Node is in scope.

Comment: At the end of your program, if you run `gc.collect()` and there are still 1.1 million objects in generation 2, then the objects that you think are are free almost certainly aren't.  There is some reference(s) to those objects that are keeping them alive.  Some variable somewhere, or some value in some dictionary.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga.  Not true.  Python can deal with cyclic references.

Comment: @FrankYellin I know, my point is that if there is some node still alive somewhere because it is referenced *as part of something that isn't a reference cycle* then the whole graph will be alive

Comment: Note that if you are really stuck trying to figure out what's going on, call `gc.collect()` and then `gc.objects()` to get a list of all live objects.  Find one that you're sure ought to have been garbage collected already, and use `gc.referents()` to find out what's keeping it alive.  See the documentation for more details.

Comment: Can you gather a live core for your program, after it has started to get large, and post it somewhere?